# How can I make my java code better in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

Here is my piece of code in java I need to convert it to Kotlin and Data is `AutoValue` class
where position is `Optional<Integer>`  and uri is `Optional<String>`

and the Data class is converted to Kotlin Data class 
I am wondering how can I convert in nice way `data.uri().isPresent()` to Kotlin. should I use let or there is better way.

````
 public static Component create(Data data) {
        Component.Builder builder =
                create(data.location()).toBuilder();

        if (data.position().isPresent()) {
            builder = builder.integer(INDEX , data.position().get());
        }

        if (data.uri().isPresent()) {
            builder = builder.string(URI, data.targetUri().get());
        }


        return builder.build();
    }   ```

Wondering should I convert to    


fun create(data: Data): Component {
    var builder = create(data.location).toBuilder()
    data.apply {
        position?.let {
            builder =builder.integer(INDEX, it)
        }
        uri?.let {
            builder = builder.string(URI, it)
        }
    }

    return builder.build()
}
````

Comment: What you've described is probably the best way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I would do

```
fun create(data: Data): Component {
    return when {
         data.position?.isPresent() -> builder.integer(INDEX, it)
         data.uri?.isPresent() -> builder.string(URI, it)
         else -> create(data.location).toBuilder()
    }.build()
}
```

Comment: But this approach it will work one of the cases but it's possible that none of them is null

Comment: If you really want to override by priority, then your approach will be good enough :)